# Remove duplicate values from comma separated variable in Oracle

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

I have a variable *(called: all_email_list)* which contains 3 email address lists altogether. *(I found some similar question but not the same with a proper solution)*

Example: `test@asd.com, test2@asd.com,test@asd.com,test3@asd.com, test4@asd.com,test2@asd.com` (it can contain spaces between comas but not all the time)

The desired output: `test@asd.com, test2@asd.com,test3@asd.com,test4@asd.com`

```
declare
first_email_list varchar2(4000);
second_email_list varchar2(4000);
third_email_list varchar2(4000);
all_email_list varchar2(4000);

begin

    select listagg(EMAIL,',') into first_email_list from UM_USER a left join UM_USERROLLE b on (a.mynetuser=b.NT_NAME) left join UM_RULES c on (c.id=b.RULEID) where RULEID = 902;
    select listagg(EMAIL,',') into second_email_list from table2 where CFT_ID =:P25_CFT_TEAM; 
    select EMAIL into third_email_list from table3 WHERE :P25_ID = ID;


    all_email_list:= first_email_list || ',' || second_email_list || ',' || third_email_list; 

    dbms_output.put_line(all_email_list);
end;
```

Any solution to solve this in a simple way? By regex maybe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solution description. Use CTE to first split up the list of emails into rows with 1 email address per row (testd_rows). Then select distinct rows (testd_rows_unique) from testd_rows and finally put them back together with listagg. From 19c onwards you can use `LISTAGG` with the `DISTINCT` keyword.

```
set serveroutput on size 999999
clear screen
declare

  all_email_list varchar2(4000);
  l_unique_email_list varchar2(4000);
  

begin
  all_email_list := 'test@asd.com, test2@asd.com,test@asd.com,test3@asd.com, test4@asd.com,test2@asd.com';

  WITH testd_rows(email) AS
  (
  select regexp_substr (all_email_list, '[^, ]+', 1, rownum) split  
    from dual 
  connect by level <= length (regexp_replace (all_email_list, '[^, ]+'))  + 1
  ), testd_rows_unique(email) AS
  (
  SELECT distinct email FROM testd_rows
  )
  SELECT listagg(email, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY email) 
    INTO l_unique_email_list 
    FROM testd_rows_unique;

  dbms_output.put_line(l_unique_email_list);
end;
/

test2@asd.com,test3@asd.com,test4@asd.com,test@asd.com
```

But ... why are you converting rows to a comma separated string and then de-duping it ? Use `UNION` to take out the duplicate values in a single `SELECT` statement and do `LISTAGG` on the values. No regexp needed then. `UNION` will skip duplicates as opposed to `UNION ALL` which returns all the rows.

```
DECLARE
  all_email_list varchar2(4000);
BEGIN
  WITH all_email (email) AS
  (
    select email from UM_USER a left join UM_USERROLLE b on (a.mynetuser=b.NT_NAME) left join UM_RULES c on (c.id=b.RULEID) where RULEID = 902
    UNION
    select email from table2 where CFT_ID =:P25_CFT_TEAM
    UNION
    select email from table3 WHERE :P25_ID = ID
  )
  SELECT listagg(email, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY email) 
    INTO all_email_list 
    FROM all_email;

  dbms_output.put_line(all_email_list);
END;
/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But in the second solution why you need the `into third_email_list ` in the 10th line? @Koen Lostrie

Comment: Ah - that is a typo. Fixed it ! Thanks for noticing

Comment: Thanks! Does it work if my 10th line is `select address from table3 WHERE :P25_ID = ID`  instead of `select email....` ? @Koen Lostrie

Comment: it should as long as the datatypes are the same. Best way is to test it :)

Answer (score 2):

You could leverage the apex_string.split table function to simplify the code.

12c+ makes it real clean

```
select listagg(distinct column_value,',') within group (order by null)
from apex_String.split(replace('test@asd.com, test2@asd.com,test@asd.com,test3@asd.com, test4@asd.com,test2@asd.com'
                              ,' ')
                      ,',')
```

11g needs a wrapping table() and listagg doesn't support distinct.

```
select listagg(email,',') within group (order by null)
from
 (select distinct column_value email
  from table(apex_String.split(replace('test@asd.com, test2@asd.com,test@asd.com,test3@asd.com, test4@asd.com,test2@asd.com',' '),','))
);
```